# Como dividir un TableRow en dos partes iguales?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

estoy trabajando una pantalla que sera un menú, serán 4 opciones y estoy un TableLayout y en un TableRow he puesto dos botones, la situación es si hay una forma de dividir es TableRow en dos parte iguales, es que da la impresión de tener 3 "celdas".
Aquí el código que uso:

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPesquisa"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Pesquisa Larvaria"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCaptura"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Captura Adulto"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGotaGrues"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Gota Gruesa"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Seguimiento a Botiquin"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: en cada tableRow define  android:layout_weight=""  con una medida igual ya que son dos elementos, por ejemplo puedes definir en ambos .5 , 1, o 2 etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu layout actualmente se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para que se vean los 2 segmentos exactamente divididos en la pantalla usa [android:layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#LinearLayout_Layout_layout_weight).**, definiendo una medida equitativa por ejemplo  `android:layout_weight="0.5"` o  `android:layout_weight="1"` para ambas vistas (`TableRow`).

> Puede configurar [android:layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#LinearLayout_Layout_layout_weight) en vistas de elementos
>   secundarios individuales para especificar cómo el diseño lineal divide
>   el espacio restante entre las vistas que contiene. Consulte la guía de
>   diseño lineal para ver un ejemplo.

**Es importante mencionar que no se necesita definir [android:weightSum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) ya que el sistema operativo calcula la medida adecuada.**

Este seria el código:

```
   <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPesquisa"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Pesquisa Larvaria"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCaptura"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Captura Adulto"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGotaGrues"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Gota Gruesa"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Seguimiento a Botiquin"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />
    </TableRow>
```

Se obtendría una medida uniforme en cada `TableRow`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el atributo **android:weightSum** . Por ejemplo algo así:

```
<TableLayout android:weightSum="2">
        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Aqui un ejemplo:

```
<TableLayout 
    android:weightSum="2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="@android:color/black">
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

WeightSum lo podrás utilizar en la mayoria de layouts. Te recomiendo que dejando la facilidad de un tablelayout o Linearlayout, comiences a utilizar  ConstraintLayout que es mucho más versátil y puedes hacer este mismo efecto tranquilamente.